# Merge Yaml File before parsing so that config is re-usable

Tags: symfony, yaml

My application uses yaml configuration to store metadata information. 
I store data about some display options.

```
Eg: 
my_page:
    title: My Title
    type: Numeric
    format: 
      align: right
      decimal: 3
```

But I want to be able to separate the configuration of format to a separate file so that I can re-use them.

So, it will be like

type.yml:

```
numeric: &numeric
  align: right
  decimal: 3
```

pages.yml

```
my_page:
    title: My Title
    type: Numeric
    format: *numeric
my_page_2:
    title: Title 2
    type: Numeric
    format: *numeric
```

Problem is; if the content of type.yml would be in config.yml, *numeric in example would work to reference it. It wouldn't work, as it's in different file.

Question: Is there anyway, I can merge those files together and parse. I'm using symfony 2.1 Yaml parser.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Config component: http://symfony.com/doc/2.1/components/config/introduction.html.

It's just more complex to configure this component, but more flexible in use. Hope, it will help to solve all you problems with configuratuib.